# Native ads in flutter between to posts fetched from wordpress?

Tags: flutter, admob, native, ads

I am making an app, that fetch posts from my wordpress blog. I want to add native ads between fetched posts. I tried searching online, where it only shows examples for normal list and not for lists as in my case. Below is the code of the file I used to grab data from wordpress blog.

I want to put the Native Ad In the same widget tree, between posts. Could you please help me. Thank you.

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress_app/common/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress_app/models/Article.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress_app/pages/single_Article.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress_app/widgets/articleBox.dart';
import 'package:flutter_wordpress_app/widgets/articleBoxFeatured.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:loading/indicator/ball_beat_indicator.dart';
import 'package:loading/loading.dart';

class Articles extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArticlesState createState() => _ArticlesState();
}

class _ArticlesState extends State<Articles> {
  List<dynamic> featuredArticles = [];
  List<dynamic> latestArticles = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureLastestArticles;
  Future<List<dynamic>> _futureFeaturedArticles;
  ScrollController _controller;
  int page = 1;
  bool _infiniteStop;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureLastestArticles = fetchLatestArticles(1);
    _futureFeaturedArticles = fetchFeaturedArticles(1);
    _controller =
        ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0, keepScrollOffset: true);
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    _infiniteStop = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchLatestArticles(int page) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
          '$WORDPRESS_URL/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=$page&per_page=10&_fields=id,date,title,content,custom,link');
      if (this.mounted) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          setState(() {
            latestArticles.addAll(json
                .decode(response.body)
                .map((m) => Article.fromJson(m))
                .toList());
            if (latestArticles.length % 10 != 0) {
              _infiniteStop = true;
            }
          });
          return latestArticles;
        }
        setState(() {
          _infiniteStop = true;
        });
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw 'No Internet connection';
    }
    return latestArticles;
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchFeaturedArticles(int page) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
          "$WORDPRESS_URL/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories[]=$FEATURED_ID&page=$page&per_page=10&_fields=id,date,title,content,custom,link");

      if (this.mounted) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          setState(() {
            featuredArticles.addAll(json
                .decode(response.body)
                .map((m) => Article.fromJson(m))
                .toList());
          });

          return featuredArticles;
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _infiniteStop = true;
          });
        }
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw 'No Internet connection';
    }
    return featuredArticles;
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    var isEnd = _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange;
    if (isEnd) {
      setState(() {
        page += 1;
        _futureLastestArticles = fetchLatestArticles(page);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/icon.png'),
            height: 45,
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                featuredPost(_futureFeaturedArticles),
                latestPosts(_futureLastestArticles)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget latestPosts(Future<List<dynamic>> latestArticles) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: latestArticles,
      builder: (context, articleSnapshot) {
        if (articleSnapshot.hasData) {
          if (articleSnapshot.data.length == 0) return Container();
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                  children: articleSnapshot.data.map((item) {
                final heroId = item.id.toString() + "-latest";
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SingleArticle(item, heroId),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: articleBox(context, item, heroId),
                );
              }).toList()),
              !_infiniteStop
                  ? Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 30,
                      child: Loading(
                          indicator: BallBeatIndicator(),
                          size: 60.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor))
                  : Container()
            ],
          );
        } else if (articleSnapshot.hasError) {
          return Container();
        }
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 150,
            child: Loading(
                indicator: BallBeatIndicator(),
                size: 60.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor));
      },
    );
  }

  Widget featuredPost(Future<List<dynamic>> featuredArticles) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: featuredArticles,
        builder: (context, articleSnapshot) {
          if (articleSnapshot.hasData) {
            if (articleSnapshot.data.length == 0) return Container();
            return Row(
                children: articleSnapshot.data.map((item) {
              final heroId = item.id.toString() + "-featured";
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SingleArticle(item, heroId),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: articleBoxFeatured(context, item, heroId));
            }).toList());
          } else if (articleSnapshot.hasError) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 60, 0, 0),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/no-internet.png",
                    width: 250,
                  ),
                  Text("No Internet Connection."),
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    label: Text("Reload"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _futureLastestArticles = fetchLatestArticles(1);
                      _futureFeaturedArticles = fetchFeaturedArticles(1);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 280,
              child: Loading(
                  indicator: BallBeatIndicator(),
                  size: 60.0,
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try this. Create a placeholder in your `articleBox` widget for the ad to display and make it hidden.  Then when you're rendering widgets with the loop, first check the length of the list and decide the frequency you need to display an ad (Eg: a list with 10 items, you can choose to display an ad after every 5 items). Then inside the loop, check the current key and unhide the placeholder and inject the ad.

Comment: Please check the code I sent you

Answer (score 2):

You can use admob_flutter package for ads inside a list view
Step 1 : Install the package admob_flutter
Step 2 : Add the class at the end of this file

```
    class AdmobManager {
      static bool _isTest = false;
    
      /** Test IDs **/
      static String test_app_id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
      static String test_banner_id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    
      /** You real IDs **/
      static String app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
      static String banner_id = "YOUR_BANNER_ID";
    
      static Admob initAdMob() {
        print("initAdMob");
        return Admob.initialize(_isTest ? test_app_id : app_id);
      }
    
      static AdmobBanner bottomBanner = AdmobBanner(
        adUnitId: _isTest ? test_banner_id : banner_id,
        adSize: AdmobBannerSize.FULL_BANNER
      );
    
      static AdmobBanner finishBanner = AdmobBanner(
        adUnitId: _isTest ? test_banner_id : banner_id,
        adSize: AdmobBannerSize.FULL_BANNER,
      );
    }
```

Step 3 : add

```
   AdmobManager.initAdMob();
```

below the super.initState(); at initState()

EG:

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AdmobManager.initAdMob();}
```

Step 4 : Replace your code with this code in latest post

```
Widget latestPosts(Future<List<dynamic>> latestArticles) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: latestArticles,
      builder: (context, articleSnapshot) {
        if (articleSnapshot.hasData) {
          if (articleSnapshot.data.length == 0) return Container();
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             
              
              Column(
                  children: articleSnapshot.data.asMap().map((index,item)=> 
                MapEntry(index,
                 Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                   
                    if(index%5 ==0)
                    AdmobManager.finishBanner,
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SingleArticle(item, item.id.toString() + "-latest"),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: articleBox(context, item, item.id.toString() + "-latest"),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              )).values.toList()),
              !_infiniteStop
                  ? Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 30,
                      child: 
                      
                      ColorLoader4())
                  : Container()
            ],
          );
        } else if (articleSnapshot.hasError) {
          return Container();
        }
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 150,
            child: 
            ColorLoader4()
                
                );
      },
    );
  }
```

Step 5 : do you have any problem till ??

Comment: I need to implement 'native ads'. I will try this thougj, can you update to native ads?

Answer (score 0):

Change map function in to -

```
articleSnapshot.data.asMap().entries.map((item) {
                final heroId = item.value.id.toString();
                if (item.key % 5 == 0) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Divider(),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  SingleArticle(item.value, heroId),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: articleBox(context, item.value, heroId),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              SingleArticle(item.value, heroId),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: articleBox(context, item.value, heroId));
                  );
                }
              }).toList()
```